# Chef 13 syntax changes

Tags: ruby, syntax, chef-infra, chef-recipe

Trying to upgrade chef client from version 12 to 13 I'm facing some issues mostly related to syntax changes

```
node['java']['webapps'].each do |object|
        name = object[0]
        attributes = object[1]
          if attributes.attribute?('enabled')
                if attributes.enabled
                        if attributes.attribute?('x')
                                if attributes.x.attribute?('conf')
                                        attributes.x.conf.each do |conf_file|
                                                template "#{x_conf_dir}/#{conf_file}" do
                                                  source "#{conf_file}.erb"
                                                  mode '0755'
                                                  owner 'tomcat'
                                                  group 'tomcat'
                                                end
                                        end
                                end
                        end
                end
        end
end
```

Chef client errors out on "if attributes.enabled" which on version 12 worked fine (it should continue if the enabled=true in the array)

now i'm hitting  "undefined method 'enabled'"

What is the correct syntax for checking the value in the array ?

Answer (score 1):

That has to be `attributes['enabled']` now, but that code can be massively cleaned up anyway. I think this does the same thing, using the `node.read` method which is like `Hash#dig`:

```
node['java']['webapps'].each do |name, app_attrs|
  conf_file = app_attrs.read('enabled', 'x', 'conf')
  if conf_file
    template .. same stuff here
  end
end
```

Any time you see that much diagonal indentation, probably rethink your code :)